# Sending event from an application to EventBridge

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, architecture, event-handling, aws-event-bridge

I'm a software engineer transitionning to cloud architecture. I've been tasked with implementing a system to compute and save stats in real time. I designed a system but I feel like I'm missing something.

My backend sends events (for instance, "a new object has been bought") and I want my system to consume those events by spawning lambdas that will update data in DynamoDB. Since there will be a lot of events, I don't want to spawn one lambda per event but queue those events and consume them with a number of lambda that would scale according to the number of events in the queue. Here's what I done:

[image]

In my head, my backend send a basic POST to API Gateway with the event info. API Gateway sends the event to eventbridge. Eventbridge will then dispatch it to the available lambdas. When I want to read data, I send a GET to API Gateway that will read from DynamoDB.

I struggle with two things:

- I thought that EventBridge could "queue" incoming events but I'm starting to doubt that. Should I add SQS and change the way I "create event" to handle every request ?
- Am I wrong with the way I would send my messages ? Should my backend send message directly to EventBridge or should my backend send a message to API Gateway, then spanw a lambda that will send an event to eventbridge ? I'm starting to think that I'm overengineering it

Comment: I think it may be appropriate to simply replace EventBridge in your architecture with either SQS or Kinesis. As for the API versus direct to EventBridge question, having the API lets you change the backend implementation (such as changing it to Kinesis or SQS) without the client needing to care. Keeping the API let's the client send requests with a basic HTTP library instead of having to use an AWS SDK.

Comment: Thank you for answering. SQS might work but you would still need something to consume it and spawn lambdas ? I don't really see how to implement it. Kinesis seems perfect but looks overkill, will take a look. 
Your explanation of API vs EventBridge is clear, thank you.

Comment: AWS Lambda has direct integration with SQS. The Lambdas will spawn automatically to consume the SQS messages.